# How to add a static IP address to a network interface using systemd.networkd, if the filesystem is read-only?

Tags: systemd, readonly

I have a situation where I'd like to add a static IP address to one of the network devices on an embedded Linux machine, via systemd.networkd.

Normally I'd do that by creating a file like `/etc/systemd/network/eno1.network` and specifying the IP address (etc) inside that file, but in this case the root partition's filesystem (where `/etc/` is located) is read-only, so I can't create a file there.

Is there a way to get systemd to read config files from an additional location (e.g. from `/tmp` or somewhere else that I could write to), or alternatively to get systemd to add a static IP address without having to first write config info to a file on the root partition?

Comment: Although not really needed in your case, bind mounting on a file is handy.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is a simple answer to this: you can place `networkd` configuration files in `/run/systemd/network`, which is writeable even on an otherwise read-only filesystem.

Comment: FWIW, it's because `/run` has another filesystem mounted on it (most likely a tmpfs).

Comment: /run/systemd imust be on writable tmpfs filesystem. which of course does not persist after reboot.